# Why does `decode(_:forKey:)` ignore its first parameter?

Tags: swift, codable

It seems like `decode(_forKey:)` ignores its first parameter, and instead relies on the generic parameter to decide what type to decode. If this is the case, what is the first parameter for?

```
class Cat: Codable {
    func speak() -> String { return "Meow" }
}

class Lion: Cat {
    override func speak() -> String { return "Roar!" }
}

class Person: Codable {
    let firstPet: Cat
    let secondPet: Cat
    init(firstPet: Cat, secondPet: Cat) {
        self.firstPet = firstPet
        self.secondPet = secondPet
    }

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case firstPet, secondPet }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.firstPet = try container.decode(Lion.self, forKey: .firstPet)
        let typeOfCat: Cat.Type = Lion.self
        self.secondPet = try container.decode(typeOfCat, forKey: .secondPet)
    }
}

let before = Person(firstPet: Lion(), secondPet: Lion())
let after = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: JSONEncoder().encode(before))
after.firstPet.speak() //"Roar!"
after.secondPet.speak() //"Meow" ...really?
```

Comment: The first parameter is used to specialize the generic parameter to the call. It's a bit strange to pass an instance of a subclass metatype in a variable of the superclass metatype and pass it in — is there something specific you need to do here that prevents you from passing in `Lion.self` directly?

Comment: But the generic parameter can be inferred from what the caller does with the return value, no? (Yes, of course in this example I could pass `Lion.self`, but what I'd really like to do is decode various subclasses determined at runtime.)

Comment: No, not always — there are cases where relying on the return type can lead to ambiguity which is difficult to track down; passing a metatype argument is the only guaranteed way to prevent that ambiguity. It's possible for the code to use the concrete metatype passed in instead of the generic argument, but this is a pretty unique use case. It should be possible for you to switch on types at runtime and call decode with the correct static type, though.

Comment: Interesting--I suppose your first comment is actually the answer. Want to write it up? (And, I can't switch because not even the *possible* types are known at compile time--I had to make some suspicious use of `superDecoder()` instead, so I could call `init(from:)` directly on the correct type.)

Comment: Posted, thanks! BTW, if you consider this to be a bug, please file it on [bugs.swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metatype parameter to the `decode(...)` calls is used to specialize the generic parameter. Swift doesn't have syntax for manually specializing generics like C++ does (e.g. `decode<Int>(forKey: ...)`), so this is a way to bind the generic parameter to a concrete type.

The benefit of passing in a metatype (instead of, say, relying on the return type to provide resolution) is that the result of the expression is unambiguous. Relying on the return result can lead to some surprising situations:

```
protocol DefaultInitializable {
    init()
}

func defaultValue<T : DefaultInitializable>() -> T {
    return T()
}

func foo(_ value: Int) {
    print(value)
}

foo(defaultValue())
```

results in

```
Untitled.swift:13:5: error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
foo(defaultValue())
    ^
Untitled.swift:5:6: note: in call to function 'defaultValue'
func defaultValue<T : DefaultInitializable>() -> T {
     ^
```

With an explicit metatype, this is a non-issue.

As for why the generic type is used over the concrete instance of the metatype you pass in — it's generally unexpected to have a concrete metatype instance have a different static type than itself.